# Cannot send forwarding mail

Tags: email, smtp

I have an xmail server "mailserver.idv" 
however , when I buy domain name from Google Domains , there is a Email Forwarding Service.
Now I have 2 kinds of mail address:

1. user@mailserver.idv is a really account on my "mailserver.idv" mail server
2. test@mailserver.idv is a forwarding mail to my g-mail "test@gmail.com"

I can send mail from user@mailserver.idv to test@gmail.com directly
But I cant send user@mailserver.idv to test@mailserver.idv

I noticed that in smail logs, it's diff. between SMTP & LOCAL

How can I set config file to send all mail as out "SMTP" always?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by add  mailproc.tab under /domains/mailserver.idv/test/

"redirect"[tab]"test@gmail.com"[newline]